# How to connect Arduino Nano to Thermal Printer via serial connection

Tags: arduino-nano

I have a generic Arduino Nano board that uses the old bootloader. I have the printer and the Arduino connected like so:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include "Adafruit_Thermal.h"

// Here's the new syntax when using SoftwareSerial (e.g. Arduino Uno) ----
// If using hardware serial instead, comment out or remove these lines:

#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#define TX_PIN 5 // Arduino transmit  YELLOW WIRE  labeled RX on printer
#define RX_PIN 6 // Arduino receive   GREEN WIRE   labeled TX on printer

SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN); // Declare SoftwareSerial obj first
Adafruit_Thermal printer(&mySerial);     // Pass addr to printer constructor
// Then see setup() function regarding serial & printer begin() calls.

// Here's the syntax for hardware serial (e.g. Arduino Due) --------------
// Un-comment the following line if using hardware serial:

//Adafruit_Thermal printer(&Serial1);      // Or Serial2, Serial3, etc.

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() {

  // This line is for compatibility with the Adafruit IotP project pack,
  // which uses pin 7 as a spare grounding point.  You only need this if
  // wired up the same way (w/3-pin header into pins 5/6/7):
  // pinMode(BUILTIN, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, LOW);

  // NOTE: SOME PRINTERS NEED 9600 BAUD instead of 19200, check test page.
  mySerial.begin(9600);  // Initialize SoftwareSerial
  //Serial1.begin(19200); // Use this instead if using hardware serial
  printer.begin();        // Init printer (same regardless of serial type)

  // The following calls are in setup(), but don't *need* to be.  Use them
  // anywhere!  They're just here so they run one time and are not printed
  // over and over (which would happen if they were in loop() instead).
  // Some functions will feed a line when called, this is normal.

  // Font options
  printer.setFont('B');
  printer.println("FontB");
  printer.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
  printer.setFont('A');
  printer.println("FontA (default)");
  printer.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");



  printer.sleep();      // Tell printer to sleep
  delay(3000L);         // Sleep for 3 seconds
  printer.wake();       // MUST wake() before printing again, even if reset
  printer.setDefault(); // Restore printer to defaults
}

void loop() {
}
```

When I run my code or reset no prints get sent to the print.

Here's what I've tried.

- Ensure power is on on both devices
- Try baud rate 19200
- Swop Tx and Rx cables around
- Tried D5 and D6 for Tx and Rx

Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: the printer cannot detect the data signals because it has no ground reference ...connect grounds together

Comment: Sorry I didn't show that in my diagram but I did connect ground and 5vcc together with the Arduino and the thermal printer. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: the Vcc should no be connected ... the printer should have its own power supply

Comment: Tell what printer that is! It does not look like having a serial interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your additional info about your printer tells me that it has a Bluetooth and a USB interface - but I can not see any other serial connection port.

So there is no way connecting this printer as-is to the arduino nano by some digital port pins.

You may decide to either buy the Thermal printer offered by Adafruit our search for a Thermal printer that clearly states that is has a "Serial Interface" or "Serial RS232 Interface" - no matter if that comes with "TTL" or not like the Adafruit printer.

The printer is intended to be connected to a USB host port (of an PC or RPi or so) or via Bluetooth (to an PC or Android phone).

It may offers a virtual serial interface over both USB and Bluetooth, but that is a speculation.

*It may be possible to hack your printer. I think the Adafruit printer was modded by Adafruit. They may have bought a stock-printer and added the connector for the TTL interface. This may also be possible with the printer you have, but that is not in the scope of your question and highly speculative.*

Comment: Sorry man, it's a Chinese machine I can't find a datasheet for it. It's made by Andowl. This site has the most information I've seen: https://www.electromannsa.com/products/goojprt-58mm-wireless-bluetooth-thermal-receipt-printer